# Vba change position of the data in Copy method

Tags: vba

I use a copy method to get data from A worksheet to B worksheet. However,  the result is not what I expected.

```
 For Each ss in yesno
 If ss.Cells.Value ="yes" Then
     Set rng = Union(.Range("A" & ss.Row),
                     .Range("C" & ss.Row),
                     .Range("B" & ss.Row),
                     .Range("D" & ss.Row))
     tlr = tws.Range("A" & tws.Row.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1).Row
     rng.Copy tws.Cells(tlr,"A")
 ElseIf ss.Cells.Value = "no" Then
 End If
 Next
```

The issue I think it happen in the "set rng Union" line. I expect the data result is from range A ,C,B,D
but it still display as A,B,C,D. No matter how I change the order. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Nicholas lui. Not sure if this is possible with the Union function. It basically selects the lower bounds of your range in this case "A" and the upper bounds in this case is "D" and creates a new range which would be A:D. It ignores the order of the union.  One possibility would be to write a custom function that takes the order or cells into an array and manually copies each cell. A bit dirty, but should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A range is a block of cells **in the order they appear** on the worksheet - you can't change the order of cells within a range or a worksheet. The `Union()` method returns a `Range` object and so it doesn't matter what order you load the cells or ranges in, they are still stored in the same order at the same location on the worksheet.

What you can do however is generate a single dimension array from your source data and use that instead. Replace your code above with this:

```
For Each ss in yesno
    If ss.Cells.Value ="yes" Then   

        vArray = Array(.Range("A" & ss.Row).Value,
                       .Range("C" & ss.Row).Value,
                       .Range("B" & ss.Row).Value,
                       .Range("D" & ss.Row).Value)

        tlr = tws.Range("A" & tws.Row.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1).Row
        tws.Cells(tlr, "A").Resize(1, 4).Value = vArray
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi @Marco Man i got compile error: invalid or unqualified reference- it highlights the word Range in the arrary

Comment: I've copied your code - which must be in side of a `With` block?

Comment: I m not sure what should i keep or replace do i remove the for each method n replace yours?

Comment: I've edited my answer - just replace the code you provided with what I've posted and it should be fine.

Comment: Do you know how to add an extra column but that column fill in with value "yes" in Column E  ?

Comment: Add another element to the array of `"Yes"` and change the resize to `.Resize(1, 5)`

Comment: but i m not extract the data from first sheet. I just want to add a new column. Array could work with this ? like `Cell.value = "yes"`

Comment: Yes, an array will accept most things: `vArray = Array(Range("A1").Value, Range("B1").Value, "yes", 123, True)`